# How to access the atomic vector attributes?

Tags: r, vector, attributes, atomic

I have set the attributes for a variable using the attr function as below :

```
x <- 1 :20
attr(x,'name') <- c("RED","BLUE")
attributes(x)

$name
[1] "RED"  "BLUE"
```

Now that I have set the attributes; if I access it using `'$`' it says `"Error : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"`. I also tried `x['name']` which shows `NA`

How do I access this atomic vector attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question,

```
 attr(x, 'name')
#[1] "RED"  "BLUE"
```

Or

```
 attributes(x)$name
#[1] "RED"  "BLUE"
```

Comment: ya, was looking for the attributes(x)$name. Thanks! :)

Comment: @ShashaankSivakumar  You have to access it by how you created.  For example, the other way to create would be `attributes(x)$NAME <- c("RED", "BLUE")`